# generated SQL throws errors

Tags: sql, orm, h2

I'm using Visual Studio with an add-in to create ORM database models and generate SQL from them. It turns out that the SQL throws errors. Here's a part:

```
CREATE TABLE ORMModel1.Milking
(
    employeeName CHARACTER VARYING(32672) NOT NULL,
    parlorNumber SMALLINT CHECK (parlorNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 2) CHECK (parlorNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 255) NOT NULL,
    startDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    cowName CHARACTER VARYING(32672) NOT NULL,
    lipidity FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
    volume FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Milking_PK PRIMARY KEY(employeeName, startDate, parlorNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Milking_UC1 UNIQUE(employeeName, cowName, startDate),
    CONSTRAINT Milking_UC2 UNIQUE(cowName, startDate, parlorNumber)
);
```

The error thrown is:

```
expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, REFERENCES, ,, )";
```

but I have no clue what it means (and I'm kind of disappointed, as I hoped the auto-generated SQL would be plug-and-play)

Since this is a school assignment, I'm using www.h2database.com to test the SQL. I'm not sure if the error is in my SQL or maybe in the H2 software, but either way I can't continue my project. At the moment, H2 is the only access I have to an SQL server.

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: the `employeeName` is duplicated?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem, i suppose. I'm defining several uniqueness constraints with unique combinations of columns, which is necessary and should be possible

Comment: Are you sure that plugin you're using is set to the right SQL dialect?  According to my reading of [the manual](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_type) h2 doesn't support `character varying` ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem is solved when changing line 4 to:

```
parlorNumber SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK (parlorNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 2),
```

Comment: yes. i tested http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67018, but how about the `VARYING(32672)` something like the max is 8000?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I was in fact using the wrong dialect. Turns out the closest thing to H2 is MySQL. Got it all figured out :)